# Syntaxt highlighting and syntax checker for Antlr4 language

Tags: antlr4

I did a grammar with antlr4 and I was wondering what tools are available to create a IDE for my own language. I'd like to make an IDE that supports syntax highlighting, syntax checker and autocompletion. However, I've no idea where to start.

Does anybody has already done one based on a Antlr4 grammar ?

Thanks,

Adrien